# Receive & Parse from socket using AsyncTask or Service or thread

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, android-asynctask, android-service

I need to monitor client received data, and update the GUI every specific time unit, I need each time the client connect to the Server then the server has to monitor its data or send to this client.

I have confused what is the good approach to use?

thread or AsyncTask or Service ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to monitor a client, I assume this will be a long running operation. So use a Service.

Use an AsyncTask only if you know for certain that the time period for which you will be monitoring will not be for long and you expect it the device orientation will not change during this period (you can work around this but why....). You can also use a thread but the problem is a thread resets if the device orientation changes (which might be ok in some cases) but stick to a regular Service.

You can either use an IntentService and do your work in the onHandleIntent() method which does the work in a separate thread or you can do your work in a new thread in a normal Service. Don't forge that you will have to post changes to the UI thread using a Handler.

Comment: Just make sure you create a new thread in the regular service , since service starts in UI thread and keep it unbounded to activity. You can look into intent service to which is in background thread but is bounded to activity cycle be default

Comment: Oops.. I was thinking about IntentService and did not realize the implications of a regular Service.. thanks for pointing it out.